# Disable command parameters for 'commands' or exe's in Start Menu search?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, search, path, start-menu

This is a bit complicated so bear with me: Basically, the Windows 7/10 Start Menu search includes results from executable in the PATH environment variable and the App Paths registry key (SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths).

So if you enter "regedi" into the search bar, you won't get any results, but 'regedit" does, because it exists in C:\Windows which is a PATH entry. [Another example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnNxM.png).

This is not a problem, but if you keep typing, "regedit fsfsdf" it locks on to what you've typed, and now you're typing a full command for regedit. The "fsfsdf" part will be treated as an argument of regedit when you press enter or click on the search result.

Now I use FL Studio 12, and the executable is FL.exe which is installed to the App Paths registry entry. When I type in FL Studio and press enter, it attempts to open "FL.exe Studio" with Studio as an argument, and throws an error that Studio doesn't exist and can't be opened.

Is there a way to disable arguments when entering the name of an executable in PATH or App Paths?

Edit: I realize I can just delete the FL.exe entry from App Paths, but am wondering if there is more to it - maybe some option to disable it somewhere in registry.

Comment: `"FL Studio 12.exe"` should work.  You can also just pin a shortcut, to the executable, to your start menu.  "Is there a way to disable arguments " - There are a half dozen system level functions that use arguments to executable located in those directories.  Disabling arguments would break your system, if it were possible, a Win32 executable accepting arguments isn't something you can disable.  I just use the `run` capability instead to run executable with spaces ( or rename the file or create a shortcut )

Comment: @Ramhound I mean disabling arguments specifically in the search bar. I've never heard of anyone running commands with arguments in the search bar, when they can do it in Run or CMD etc.